# How to show GROUP BY data in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

MySQL Table: Images

```
id | Rating |
 1 | 3.0    |
 2 | 3.2    |
 3 | 4.7    |
 4 | 2.4    |
 5 | 2.4    |
 6 | 4.3    |
 7 | 2.4    |
 8 | 3.2    |
```

I'm basically trying to query the above table to get the data from those 2 fields (id and Rating) so that I can produce an 'Image of the Month' page. 
I can query the database as so:

```
 $rows = @mysql_rows('SELECT ID FROM Image WHERE Live = 1 AND '.$whereDateLive.' ORDER BY Rating Desc LIMIT 15');
```

which gives me all the ID's of the images. I then use a foreach loop to build my list of Images in descending order from the highest rated, with something like -

```
foreach($rows as $row)
    {
    $img = new Image($row['ID'],true);
$content .= '<img src="/images/'.$img.'.jpg">';
}
```

This gives me a very basic list with no sorting (e.g 1st place, 2nd place etc). What I'm trying to do is GROUP the id's by Rating, because as you can see from the table, Images ID 2 & 8 have the same rating (3.2) so would be Joint 3rd place. I can do this in theory with the following:

```
 $rows = @mysql_rows('SELECT ID FROM Image WHERE Live = 1 AND '.$whereDateLive.' GROUP BY Rating ORDER BY Rating Desc LIMIT 15');
```

Which gives me the data grouped how I need, However, the foreach loop then only shows 1 image of the group (the first in the group), so is obviously not the right thing to use. What I want to know is there a PHP function that will display the data by how it is grouped? or is something wrong in my code. Thank you.

Desired results, what I'm working towards, would be (as requested below) -

```
Image of the Month Page Title
------------------------------
First Place
[imgid 3]
-----------
Second Place
[imgid 6]
-----------
Third Place
[imgid 2] [imgid 8]
----------
Best of the rest
(showing any image with a rating > 2.4)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of filed `Rating`??

Comment: Hi, it is data type 'double'

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You have different images identified by `id`. Each image has a `rating`. You can order the images by rating and you can limit your results then to only get the 15 best rated for instance. But what does all this have to do with grouping and months?

Comment: BTW: `double` is a data type you'd almost never use, because it's an approximate type (which can lead to anomalities like 0.1+0.1+0.1 <> 0.3). You would always use precise types like `decimal`. Only if the range wouldn't suffice you would use double. Most of us will never in our lives encounter a situation where the `decimal` numeric range does not suffice.

Comment: Could you please show the desired results? Is Kostas Mitsarakis right, gusseing you want all top-15 rated IDs, no matter how many they are?

Comment: No, the limit is irrelevant. The goal is to show the top 3 images, but if there is more than one with identical rating, to show them grouped under same heading. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Forgot to say - I have edited my initial post to show desired results as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select both ID and rating from the table. Order by rating, so as to get the best rated images first.

```
$rows = @mysql_rows
  ('select id, rating from image where live = 1 and '.$whereDateLive.' order by rating');
```

Then have a loop in PHP in which you consider the rating. In pseudo code:

```
$rating = -1;
$position = 0;

foreach($rows as $row)
{
  $img = new Image($row['id'], true);
  if(($row['rating'] = $rating) or $position > 3 then
  {
    <show the image next to the one before>
  }
  else
  {
    ++$position;
    $rating = $row['rating'];
    <show the title "n.th place" according to $position>
    <show the image>
  }
}
```

Comment: As to only showing images rated > 2.4, you can add this to your where clause of course: `and rating > 2.4`.

Comment: Can't thank you enough Thorsten, it works a treat and is not as complicated as I thought it would be. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I 've just checked this and it had no errors but something tells me that those ORDER and LIMIT in inner join don't seem very good. But you can try it ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3271/1) has limit 5 to keep it brief). Also note that you have to adjust it accordingly your `PHP` variables.

```
SELECT aa.id, aa.rating
FROM Image AS aa
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT rating
    FROM Image
    GROUP BY rating
    ORDER BY rating DESC
    LIMIT 15
) AS _aa
ON aa.rating = _aa.rating
ORDER BY aa.rating DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Thank you for that. The query works, but when I put my WhereDateLive clause in it (which works in previous query) it doesn't work.  $rows = @mysql_values('SELECT aa.ID, aa.Rating
FROM Image AS aa 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Rating
    FROM Image 
    GROUP BY Rating
    ORDER BY Rating DESC
    LIMIT 15
) AS _aa
ON aa.Rating = _aa.Rating 
 WHERE '.$whereDateLive.' ORDER BY aa.Rating DESC
LIMIT 15');

Comment: The $whereDateLive is basically just from a filter option, so is something like: `code` DateLive BETWEEN ' . mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')-1, 1, date('Y')) . ' AND ' . mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));

Comment: Hm, try again adding quotes, copy-paste this: "' . mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')-1, 1, date('Y')) . '" AND "' . mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'))"

Comment: Are you trying to build a dense_rank query here, i.e. show all records with the top 15 ratings no matter whether these are only 15 records or hundreds? Then you'd have to remove the last line (`LIMIT 15`). As is, you could remove the whole subquery and still get the same result, namely 15 top rated records (rather then n top-15 rated records).

Comment: Judging from your profile i am sure you are right :). I 'll try to find a better solution.